# gcc error message includes unnecessary character

Tags: c, linux, gcc, message, centos8

I have just written very simple c file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock = -1;

   /* open raw socket */
   sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0);
   if (sock == -1)
   {
      printf("socket creation failed\n");
      return -1;
   }

   /* receive packets */

   /* close raw socket */
   close(sock);

   return 0;
}
```

And tried to compile using the command "gcc packet_receive.c"
Then, I have error message like below.

```
$ gcc packet_receive.c
packet_receive.c: In function emainf:
packet_receive.c:22:2: warning: implicit declaration of function eclosef; did you mean epclosef? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  close(sock);
  ^~~~~
  pclose
```

I understand why I see this error.
But I'm wondering why I see 'e' in front of main, close, pclose from the error message.

Is there anyone seeing the same kind of error message?

Comment: Funny. Try some different console? Could be some escape codes are being interpreted weirdly

Comment: The 'e' and 'f' are supposed to be quote characters, e.g. `emainf` is supposed to be `'main'`. Evidently, the compiler is using unicode characters for the quotes, and the terminal isn't displaying them as unicode.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mojibake. See self-answer. No point to add any more.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments.
I was using teraterm and accidently set locale to Japanese.
When I chance the locale to American, the problem is solved.